# Re-Insert/Update primary key value after a mistake (restoration)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-insert, primary-key

I encounter a problem in SQL Server.

We have a table `Country` with `N_Country` as its primary key. Please note the table have like 10 columns but I am only showing these two for the example:

| N_Country | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | United Kingdom |
| 2 | España |
| 3 | France |
| 4 | Deutschland |
| 5 | Italia |

However, we do not know why, but the 3rd row (France) got deleted. Now, we only have primary keys 1/2/4/5 and no longer 3.

I can not add a row into this table as it would make a country with primary key 6, as I would need to update all my other tables which had "N = 3" to "N = 6", which is a lot of work (and I "do not know all the tables" that would need that update).

The "fastest/best" two solutions I see are:

1. I create a new row (N = 6, Name = France) and then I

   ```
    UPDATE Country
    SET N_Country = 3 
    WHERE N_Country = 6
   ```
2. I directly do

   ```
    INSERT INTO Country (N_Country, Name) 
    VALUES (3, 'France')
   ```

Both should be "safe" as I am just restoring a deleted value. I never update primary keys (as it is a really bad idea) but here I am stuck with the error

> IDENTITY_INSERT is defined to OFF

I saw from related post the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT aTable ON`

I would like to know if I can use something like this?

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Country ON
GO

-- Attempt to insert an explicit ID value of 3
INSERT INTO Country (N_Country, Name) 
VALUES (3, 'France')
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT aTable OFF
GO
```

And also if you think this is "safe"? (I guess so) - But if my table Country has 10 columns, should I "INSERT" all 10 columns or can I just INSERT the two main ones, and then update later?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what happened when you tested ?

Comment: When I tried to INSERT, I got an error "IDENTITY_INSERT is defined as OFF"
When I tried to Update primary key, I got an error that "it is not possible to update a primary key"

Comment: the identity insert method should work. you can't update identity fields

Comment: The script in your question should work to re-insert the row and the other columns can be updated later. The error suggests the statements were not run on the same session/connection.

Comment: Thanks everybody. I just wanted to be sure it was safe so all good, it's working :) Have a nice day!

Comment: While it doesn't address your problem directly, I will put forth that if you have a column whose value you need to be a particular value (in this case, you need N_Country to be 3 for France) then you shouldn't be using an identity column but rather manually specifying the value yourself. Said another way, identity is good when you need a row to have _some_ value, but what value it gets doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to insert a specific value on an identity column then first

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT <schema>.<table> ON;
```

This allows with a follow up insert statement to insert a wanted value for the identity column.

Very important afterwards:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT <schema>.<table> OFF;
```

Only one ON state can exist across all tables in a database at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert just the missing records using this technique.

You need to make sure your `INDENTITY_INSERT` statements match - in your example, you set it `ON` for `Country`, but you switch it `OFF` for `aTable`. This would leave identity insert open on your `Country` table.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Country ON
INSERT INTO Country (N_Country, Name) VALUES (3, 'France') 
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Country OFF
```

Tested with schema

```
CREATE TABLE Country(
  N_Country INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  Name NVARCHAR(100)
)
```